# UICollectionView looks normal during segue, but jumps down when view is presented

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller

I have an initial view controller, which segues to a `UINavigationController` with a view containing a `UICollectionView` as the root. Here's the storyboard to illustrate:

[image]

Whenever I initiate the custom segue, this happens:

[image]

The view slides in as normal, but the moment the view is presented with `presentViewController` (within the segue implementation) the collection view seems to jump down.

A close up of the storyboard collection view:

[image]

Exploded view during the segue:

[image]

Exploded view after segue:

[image]

[Custom segue implementation](http://pastebin.com/tbVAXRn4)

I'm glad you made it all the way down here! Sorry about all the images, I just wanted to make things as easy for you as possible. I have no idea what this could be, but I suspect something to do with the navigation controller.

Comment: This happens to me too. Have you figured out what was causing the issue?

Comment: I've since moved on to another project, but maybe the answer below will be relevant to you? @Pavan Edit: Hah! Oops, I didn't realize it was you who provided the answer… thanks for that!

Comment: aha, maybe consider marking it as the right answer? ;)

Comment: @Pavan It's been a while, but I've finally marked it as the accepted answer. Sorry about the delay, and thanks for your help!

Comment: Aha, cheers mate @blerch. Merry Christmas and have a happy new year!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, what fixed it was to set the view controller's `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to `false`. This will ensure your collection view will not jump. I was also able to recreate this Collection view jumping issue when presenting the view controller inside a navigation controller, in which case it would adjust the content below the navigation bar. In this case I had to set the navigation bar's `translucent` property to `false` thus not requiring to do deal with the previous property.